# how to clear JS heap

Tags: node.js, git, version-control, next.js, heap-memory

I have an issue with my project.

[image]

I began `init git` at the beginning of a project, but failed to push my changes to the repo. I was delaying my understanding of git until later, but it appears that the code gods have demanded I figure out how the hell it works.

After I `npm run dev` my project, I receive a JS stacktrace heap limit allocation failed error.

I tried discarding the whole pending changes file but receive a "you are on a git branch yet to be born". Considering my last name is Born, this project has become very personal. Can anyone direct me from here? My other idea was to can the whole project and begin a new one without source control, but I might as well figure out how to the fix this problem now.

Comment: I assume you meant `git init` to initialize a Git repository? For Git, I suggest looking up some guides/tutorials on how git works. Just so you know, discarding your changes basically means "undoing them so it's back like the previous commit", which will **delete your git-unsaved changes**. That's why you can't discard yet, which probably saved you a lot of lost work.

Comment: @KelvinSchoofs Alright I guess I'll put in the work. Duly noted - on the delete git unsaved changed. Thanks!

Comment: Your JS error is due to uncontrolled recursion. Rename your function Header to something else like `MyHeader` and first import `Header` from mui core. Also, your 5K changes are probably because you haven't added node_modules to gitignore, or your codebase is really large.

Comment: You need to concentrate on one problem at a time: either worry about saving files in Git, or worry about fixing your infinite recursion with your headers. :-)

Answer (score 0):

That error indicates that you're basically running out of memory. This isn't surprising, since according to your code screenshot *(you should always post your code in a code block, not as an image btw)* your `Header` component is rendering another `Header` component in itself. Infinite loop, apparently one that caused you to run out of memory before you encountered a stack overflow error. *I don't know exactly how the internals of React work, so that might be normal.*